# Querying through JPA

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I have a question in fetching data through JPA,

Lets say I have an Entity and the Entity is having OnetoOne relationship as well as OneToMany to other related Entities.

Is there any API in Hibernate or JPA where in if I set few values to the Entity class and the related entity class , I get a list of Entity class matching those values.

Eg:

```
Entity e = new Entity();
e.setVar1("Test1");
e.setVar2("Test2");

SiblingEntity se = new SiblingEntity(); // OnetoOne with Entity class
se.setVar1("Var1");

e.setSiblingEntity(se);

ChildEntity ce = new ChildEntity(); // OnetoMany with Entity class
ce.setVar1("value1");

e.getChildEntities().add(ce);
```

Now we have a root Entity e with Sibling entity and Child Entity.

Is there any API which will give me the following result? like the one mentioned below:

List elist = entityDAO.getEntityList(e);

elist has to contain the list of Entity class which satisfies the conditions which we mentioned above.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You want a kind of query by example, I don't know a framework capable to do that with JPA, but JQL can be expressed quite straightforward as you do your assignments:

```
entityManager.createQuery(
   "select e from Entity e where e.var1 = 'Test1' 
    and e.var2 = 'Test2' and e.siblingEntity.var1 = 'Var1' 
    and e.childEntity.var1 = 'value1'").getResultList();
```

should deliver what you want, if the entity relations are defined correctly.

Searching for QBE and JPA I found following link:

[hibernate-query-example-qbe](https://dzone.com/articles/hibernate-query-example-qbe)

perhaps that is according to your intentions.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply @aschoerk, but I was thinking not to write any queries for that .

Comment: without using queries , the API should intelligently identify the not null values in the detached entities which we pass , do a fetch join among those and return back a list of root entities.

Comment: Thanks a lot @aschoerk , that's exactly what I was looking for